# how to debug drupal_http_request

Tags: webforms, 8

I'm working on a module that takes a form submission and posts it to a rest api, using the webform validator module's hooks.  I'm trying to debug what's going wrong, and I have the following code, which correctly displays $data and $url but nothing for $result (I'm assuming it's null?).

I'm new to drupal and I wonder what I'm doing wrong, with the http_request that it comes back null, or what else I can do to debug.

```
      $options = array( data => $data,
                        method => 'POST');
      //verify $data
      $errors['item_2'] = $data;
      $errors['item_3'] = $url


      $result = drupal_http_request($url, $options);


      // display the returned JSON result as a form error
      $errors['item_1'] = json_decode($result);
```

Comment: This function always returns an array (PHP), that you can access the status code, redirects, and the response contents. If you install Devel module, you can call dpm($result) to make it print the variable in a nice interactive display. When using API functions, API docs can be very helpful: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7

Answer (score 1):

[`drupal_http_request`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) doesn't just return the response data, it returns an object.

**Return value**

**object** An object that can have one or more of the following components:

**request**: A string containing the request body that was sent.
**code**: An integer containing the response status code, or the error code if an error occurred.
**protocol**: The response protocol (e.g. HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/1.0).
**status_message**: The status message from the response, if a response was received.
**redirect_code**: If redirected, an integer containing the initial response status code.
**redirect_url**: If redirected, a string containing the URL of the redirect target.
**error**: If an error occurred, the error message. Otherwise not set.
**headers**: An array containing the response headers as name/value pairs. HTTP header names are case-insensitive (RFC 2616, section 4.2), so for easy access the array keys are returned in lower case.
**data**: A string containing the response body that was received.

For example, you can check

```
// This is the actual response data.
drupal_set_message($result->data);
// if there's an error, it'll  be in here
drupal_set_message($result->error);
```

or, if using the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module

```
dpm($result);
```

In your case, you might just need:

```
if (empty($result->error) {
  $errors['item_1'] = json_decode($result->data);
}else{
  // An error occurred, log, show msg etc...
}
```